# A final test... again

Tags: cipher

The CIA fired you because you were too smart. Now you being recruited by the MI6 for as a spy to infiltrate the Martian space camp 123 miles away from Earth. The mission number is 456 and the 678 contestants who failed had to solve this Martian message in order to gain entry:

> t5thnht5ne3dc = ? 
>     p0;/aq1zsw2xsw2xw2sxo9l.r4fvde3c = ? 
>     i8k,sw2x = ?  
>     aq1zr4fve3dcsw2x = ?

What is the secret message and what is its relationship to Mars?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Every fourth letter (ignoring an extra 't' in the first line) spells out, "The password is Ares." Ares is the Greek counterpart of Mars, the Roman god of war.

Comment: Nice, and 4 ties in nicely too, as Mars is the 4th planet from Sol.